# SSIS processing large amount of flat files is painfully slow

Tags: sql-server, ssis

From one of our partners, I receive about 10.000 small tab delimited text files with +/- 30 records in each file. It is impossible for them to deliver it in one big file.

I process these files in a ForEach loop container. After reading a file, 4 column derivations are performed and then finally contents are stored in a SQL Server 2012 table.

This process can take up to two hours.

I already tried processing the small files into one big file and then importing this one in the same table. This process takes even more time.

Does anyone have any suggestions to speed up processing?

Comment: Your package looks like a Foreach Loop. Inside the Foreach loop, you have a Data Flow Task. The Data Flow Task has a Flat File Source. A Derived Column Transformation is connected to the Flat File Source. You then have an (OLE DB Destination or SQL Server Destination) attached to the Derived Column Transformation? If you are using the OLE DB Destination, how is it configured? You are writing to a SQL Server 2012 table but is the package itself a 2012 package or a prior version? Do the packages run on the same server the files sit on and is it also the same server as the destination table?

Comment: Make sure you are using Open Rowset Using FastLoad setting on the destination data flow.  That can significantly speed up the load process.  This will help more when you combine the files together.

Comment: Yes, in the ForEach container: Flat File Source -> Derivation -> OLE DB Destination. The destination is configured with 'Table Lock' unchecked, Data Access Mode = Fast Load and 'Check Constraints' is unchecked. The package itself is 2012 and stored on the SQL Server.

I have no file access on the SQL Server so the source files are stored on a different server.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that sounds counter intuitive is to replace your one Derived Column Transformation with 4 and have each one perform a single task. The reason this can provide performance improvement is that the engine can better parallelize operations if it can determine that these changes are independent.

- [Investigation: Can different combinations of components affect Dataflow performance?](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2011/01/12/investigation-can-different-combinations-of-components-effect-dataflow-performance.aspx)
- [Increasing Throughput of Pipelines by Splitting Synchronous Transformations into Multiple Tasks](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2010/08/18/increasing-throughput-of-pipelines-by-splitting-synchronous-transformations-into-multiple-tasks.aspx)

You *might* be running into network latency since you are referencing files on a remote server. Perhaps you can improve performance by copying those remote files to the local box before you being processing. The performance counters you'd be interested in are

- Network Interface / Current Bandwidth
- Network Interface / Bytes Total / sec
- Network Interface / Transfers/sec

The other thing you can do is replace your destination and derived column with a Row Count transformation. Run the package a few times for all the files and that will determine your theoretical maximum speed. You won't be able to go any faster than that. Then add in your Derived column and re-run. That should help you understand whether the drop in performance is due to the destination, the derived column operation or the package is running as fast as the IO subsystem can go.

Comment: Splitting work across multiple transforms only improves performance if you have multiple buffers of data. If I'm reading the original post right, he's only dealing with 30 rows per file, which would always go into a single buffer.

Comment: Curse you @mattmasson and your superior SSIS knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

Do your files offer an easy way (i.e. their names) of subdividing them into even (or mostly even) groups?  If so, you could run your loads in parallel.

For example, let's say you could divide them into 4 groups of 2,500 files each.

1. Create a Foreach Loop container for each group.
2. For your destination for each group, write your records to their own staging table.
3. Combine all recordss from all staging tables into your big table at the end.

If the files themselves don't offer an easy way to group them, consider pushing them into subfolders when your partner sends them over, or inserting the file paths into a database so you can write a query to subdivide them and use the file path field as a variable in the Data Flow task.

Comment: Thank you Kyle. The file name of each file includes month and year. I already divided the files into month, leaving about 1500 files per folder.
I managed to speed up the process by tweaking the 'Rows per batch' and Maximum insert commit size' settings in the Ole DB Destination.
It now takes about 1 hour to process the files (raw estimate since it still processing as we speak.

Comment: If each file only has ~30 rows, then it is unlikely that changing 'Rows per batch' is going to do much for you. It's likely that everything was already being committed as a single batch.